# How to get current location among all WIFI, GPS, Location Services or any other apps in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cellular-network

I need to get the user's get current location dynamically.

For this I am working with CLLocationManager for getting current location it is fine.

Now I want to get the current location using WIFI, GPS, Location Services, or from any other apps in the device(i.e that apps are already maintained the current location value).

In above all possible ways which one is maintained the less battery usage for getting current location?

How is it possible in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in Appdelegate

```
func initLocationManager() {
    seenError = false
    locationFixAchieved = false
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if (locationFixAchieved == false) {
        locationFixAchieved = true
        let locationArray = locations as NSArray
        let locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
        let coord = locationObj.coordinate
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(String(coord.latitude), forKey: "latitude")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(String(coord.longitude), forKey: "longitude")

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks!.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        } else {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })
}


func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) {
        //stop updating location to save battery life
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print(placemark.locality )
        print(placemark.postalCode )
        print(placemark.administrativeArea )
        print(placemark.country )
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(placemark.locality, forKey: "city")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(placemark.administrativeArea, forKey: "state")


}


// authorization status
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    var shouldIAllow = false

    switch status {
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
        locationStatus = "Restricted Access to location"
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
        locationStatus = "User denied access to location"
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
        locationStatus = "Status not determined"
    default:
        locationStatus = "Allowed to location Access"
        shouldIAllow = true
    }
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LabelHasbeenUpdated", object: nil)
    if (shouldIAllow == true) {
        print("Location to Allowed")
        // Start location services
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else {
        print("Denied access: \(locationStatus)")
    }
}
```

Now call *initLocationManager(*) class in *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*

Comment: @adi.......thank you for quick response.                                                                I think you are using CLLocation Manger class.I have a small doubt reg. above code. I need to know the in which way you got that data either wifi? gps? LocationServices? or any other? and also is it smart way for getting current location with less amount of battery usage.                       1.  Why are you placing this code in AppDelegate instead of our custom class?      2. Is there any specific reason for this if yes please describe me ?

Comment: or the above code is enough for all types of criteria ?

Comment: @wecan ... its not necessary to put this code in app delegate you can use this in your custom class

Comment: ok no issues with that, thank you and sorry for lately reply.  But I need to work for getting data from cellular tower signals, wifi, or any services. So in that way I want to get the data. so please guide me if any info regarding this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @WeCan  I am also facing the same issue. are you able to find user location using Wifi or cellular network?